# How to distribute the sum of several numbers similarly?

Tags: python, list, distribute

Is there a way to distribute more similarly than the method below?
I'm also curious about how to distribute it from more than one list.
The list can contain only five numbers.

```
intList = []
for i in range(10):
    intList.append(random.randint(10,200))


listX = []
listY = []

intList.sort(reverse=True)

for i in range(len(intList)):
    if sum(listX) >= sum(listY):
        if len(listY) != 5:
            listY.append(intList[i])
        else:
            listX.append(intList[i])
    else:
        if len(listX) != 5:
            listX.append(intList[i])
        else:
            listY.append(intList[i])

print(f"listx = {listX} \nlisty = {listY}\n sum x = {sum(listX)}, y = {sum(listY)}")
```

Comment: What do you mean similarly ? Minimizing the difference between the two sums of elements in list ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Minimizing the difference between the two sums of elements in list

Comment: So you are asking if your code correctly implements an algorithm to minimize the difference between the sums of the output lists?

Comment: yes I wonder if there's a better algorithm than that

Comment: @권대현 Your algorithm isn't correct, to begin with. There are many counterexamples (e.g. [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]).

Answer (score 2):

You should sort the list of integers in descending order and then iterate through it, adding each number to the list with the smaller current sum, like the following:

```py
import random

intList = []
for i in range(10):
    intList.append(random.randint(10, 200))

listX = []
listY = []

intList.sort(reverse=True)

sumX = 0
sumY = 0

for num in intList:
    if sumX <= sumY:
        listX.append(num)
        sumX += num
    else:
        listY.append(num)
        sumY += num

print(f"listx = {listX} \nlisty = {listY}\n sum x = {sumX}, y = {sumY}")
```

### Edit

To ensure that both lists have exactly 5 elements and maintain balanced lengths, you can modify the algorithm to distribute the numbers based on the lengths of the lists. If one list has fewer than 5 elements, prioritize it adding numbers to that list until it reaches 5 elements.

Try this:

```py
import random

intList = []
listX = []
listY = []

for i in range(10):
    num = random.randint(0, 5)
    intList.append(num)

intList.sort(reverse=True)

sumX = 0
sumY = 0

for num in intList:
    if len(listX) < 5:
        listX.append(num)
        sumX += num
    elif len(listY) < 5:
        listY.append(num)
        sumY += num
    elif sumX <= sumY:
        listX.append(num)
        sumX += num
    else:
        listY.append(num)
        sumY += num

print(f"listx = {listX} \nlisty = {listY}\n sum x = {sumX}, y = {sumY}")
```

Comment: +1, I'll just add that if you want less line - you can compute the sum of each list with sum(listX) and sum(listY) instead of storing them

Comment: `sum(listX) <= sum(listY) ? listX.append(num) : listY.append(num)`  if you want a one liner

Comment: I want to make sure that there are always 5 elements in each list

Comment: Sample input: [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5] will generate output lists that are balanced in weight (sums) but not in length.

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes Is there a way to divide it into two lists that are more similar than that?

Comment: @권대현 I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve, or also you have asked too many questions, see [ask]. Clarify the question correctly.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I'm sorry. I'll refer to the method and write the question all over again

Comment: @SunderamDubey I'm sorry I'm late. I wrote a detailed article explaining what I wanted in detail [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78252474/23918188)

Answer (score 0):

One counter example to your solution is:

```
[8, 7, 5, 4, 4, 1]
```

Adding as you have done would give the subsets:

```
[8, 4, 4], [7, 5, 1]: difference of sums = 3
```

while the optimal solution is:

```
[8, 5, 4], [7, 4, 1]: difference of sums = 1
```

Thus, to solve this problem, you need to brute force generate all combinations of (n choose floor(n/2)) and find the one with the smallest difference. Here is a sample code:

```py
comb = []
def getcomb(l, ind, k):
    if len(comb) == k:
        return [comb[:]]
    if ind == len(l):
        return []
    ret = getcomb(l, ind+1, k)
    comb.append(l[ind])
    ret += getcomb(l, ind+1, k)
    comb.pop()
    return ret

def get_best_split(l):
    lsm = sum(l)
    best = lsm
    a = []
    for i in getcomb(l, 0, len(l)//2):
        sm = sum(i)
        if abs(sm - (lsm - sm)) < best:
            best = abs(sm - (lsm - sm))
            a = i

    b = [x for x in l if x not in a]
    return best, a, b

print(get_best_split([8, 7, 5, 4, 4, 1])) 
# outputs (1, [7, 4, 4], [8, 5, 1])
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't care about the subsets themselves, then you can just generate all possible sums:

```py
def getcomb(l, ind, k, val):
    if k == 0:
        return [val]
    if ind == len(l):
        return []
    return getcomb(l, ind+1, k, val) + getcomb(l, ind+1, k-1, val + l[ind]) 

def get_best_split(l):
    l = sorted(l, reverse=True)
    best = 1000000
    for i in getcomb(l, 0, len(l)//2, 0):
        best = min(best, abs(i - (sum(l) - i)))
    return best
```

**EDIT 2:**
Another interesting thing to try out might be a modified knapsack solution, where you keep track of the set of the number of elements that can make each value. The complexity would be N^2 * sum(L), which is arguably better than N choose (N/2) depending on how large the average element in your list is:

```py
def get_best_split_knapsack(l):
    sm = sum(l)
    dp = [[-1, set()] for _ in range(sm+1)]
    dp[0][0] = 1
    dp[0][1].add(0)

    best = sm 

    for i in l:
        for j in range(sm//2, i-1, -1):
            if dp[j-i][0] == 1:
                dp[j][0] = 1
                dp[j][1].update(k+1 for k in dp[j-i][1])
        
        for j in range(max(0,int(sm//2-best)), min(int(sm//2+best)+1, sm)):
            if dp[j][0] == 1 and len(l)//2 in dp[j][1]:
                best = min(best, abs(sm/2 - j))
        
    return int(2*best)
```

Comment: @Sunderam don't make trivial edits to other people's contributions

Comment: @pho ok noted :)

Comment: How do I print out two separate lists instead of difference of sum? And each divided list must contain five elements.